# custom Crediential Provider in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

i done to develop msgina in windows xp.

now i want to change in windows 7.but there is no gina.dll there.

crediential provider do that work in win7.

So what is crediential provider.its  adll or api.

suggest some links to resolve my queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winlogon and Credential Providers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647(v=vs.85).aspx